# cloning git repo (hosted by gitea) via VS code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use the git integration from VS code to track changes on a project shared with my colleagues. The project is hosted by [gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/). I use ssh-key to have my identity checked and everything works from the command line (I have already uploaded the public key to the git repo), as shown below:

```
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add /path/to/privateKey
```

After inputting my password I get

```
Identity added: /path/to/privateKey (/path/to/privateKey)
```

Then if I try to clone the repo from the command line with

```
git clone git@vgit01x.whatever.jp:biorganic/project.git
```

everything works, I can add, stage, commit, merge and everything.

Now I want to do everything via VS code. So I first clicked on 'Clone Repository'

[image]

Then when the dialogue window popped up (I selected 'clone from URL')
I pasted the repo address `git@vgit01x.whatever.jp:biorganic/project.git`.

VSCode tries to clone the repo, but then after some time I get the following error:

```
> git clone git@vgit01x.whatever.jp:biorganic/project.git /nexus/user/gitDev/folder/project-1 --progress
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I find it odd because the clicks on VS code result in a command that works when invoked from the command line (`git clone git@vgit01x.whatever.jp:biorganic/project.git`).

Also it appears that somehow VS code does recognise the remote repo, as I see the branches and the commits using the gitlens extension, as shown below:

[image]

However, if I click on the top icon, as shown below:

[image]

it shows *you are not signed in to any accounts*, which I guess it is the cause of the error. I have a suspicion that this is because the project is hosted at gitea, not github. If I try to connect to a repo hosted by github I can login by clicking the top icon above, then I can login with gitlens, which will redirect me to the github page.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here/ what I'd need to change on VS code to successfully sign in to the remote repo to track the changes I want?

Comment: down of VScode left corner , have your login to your git host accout?

Comment: please see my edits. It appears that VS code is now connected to the remote repo. But as you pointed out, it appears that I am not signed in somehow

Comment: OK , you have to sign in then according to your last image , But first make sure that you download all git extensions from VScode market (after download close vscode and then reopen) and the try logging  in

Comment: Oh there is plenty of extensions (I have installed gitlens installed). If I click on the icon that I mentioned in my question I cannot login, can I connect with a command from the command palette?

Answer (score 0):

VSCode [SSH troubleshooting tips](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_enabling-alternate-ssh-authentication-methods) does mention:

> If you are connecting to an SSH remote host and are either:
>
> - Connecting with two-factor authentication
> - Using password authentication
> - Using an SSH key with a passphrase when the SSH Agent is not running or accessible
>
> then VS Code should automatically prompt you to enter needed information.
> If you do not see the prompt, enable the `remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal` setting in VS Code.
> This setting displays the terminal whenever VS Code runs an SSH command.
> You can then enter your authentication code, password, or passphrase when the terminal appears.

For testing, try and generate a separate ssh key without passphrase, to rule out any ssh agent side effect.

But pay attention to the SSH URL used: if your ssh key if not the default ~/.ssh/id_rsa, your remote URL should be:

```
gl:biorganic/project.git
```

With a ~/.ssh/config file with

```
Host gl
  Hostname vgit01x.whatever.jp
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey
```

(replace `mykey` with the name of the custom key generated locally, whose public key would have been registered to your vgit01x.whatever.jp user settings)